# Forming a Dataframe from two separate Dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression

I have a dataframe (Df1) that has 7 columns, each column is a variable to be used to develop a predictive linear regression model.

My second dataframe (Df2) is a TRUE/FALSE matrix, containing every possible column combination of Df1. Thus, it has 7 columns which match those of my first dataframe (Df1), containing either TRUE or FALSE, with 127 rows (the 128th row containing FALSE in each column, has been removed).

I want to create 127 dataframes, accounting for every column combination of my Df1, with the original values from Df1.

Is there a way of iterating through each row of Df2, and where 'TRUE' is found, creating a unique Df based from the Df1.

Are there any other solutions or considerations?

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  In particular questions should include reproducible input using `dput`, expected output and best code attempt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to see a concrete example, but it sounds like we can recreate your data structure like this.

> I have a dataframe (Df1) that has 7 columns, each column is a variable to be used to develop a predictive linear regression model.

We can make something similar using this code:

```r
set.seed(1)

Df1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(1:7, function(x) rnorm(10, x)))


Df1
#>           V1         V2       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7
#> 1  0.3735462  3.5117812 3.918977 5.358680 4.835476 6.398106 9.401618
#> 2  1.1836433  2.3898432 3.782136 3.897212 4.746638 5.387974 6.960760
#> 3  0.1643714  1.3787594 3.074565 4.387672 5.696963 6.341120 7.689739
#> 4  2.5952808 -0.2146999 1.010648 3.946195 5.556663 4.870637 7.028002
#> 5  1.3295078  3.1249309 3.619826 2.622940 4.311244 7.433024 6.256727
#> 6  0.1795316  1.9550664 2.943871 3.585005 4.292505 7.980400 7.188792
#> 7  1.4874291  1.9838097 2.844204 3.605710 5.364582 5.632779 5.195041
#> 8  1.7383247  2.9438362 1.529248 3.940687 5.768533 4.955865 8.465555
#> 9  1.5757814  2.8212212 2.521850 5.100025 4.887654 6.569720 7.153253
#> 10 0.6946116  2.5939013 3.417942 4.763176 5.881108 5.864945 9.172612
```

> My second dataframe (Df2) is a TRUE/FALSE matrix, containing every possible column combination of Df1. Thus, it has 7 columns which match those of my first dataframe (Df1), containing either TRUE or FALSE, with 127 rows (the 128th row containing FALSE in each column, has been removed).

This code produces a data frame of every possible combination of the 7 columns of `Df1`

```
Df2 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(as.raw(0:127), 
                      function(x) (rawToBits(x) == 0)[1:7])))


head(Df2)
#>      V1    V2    V3   V4   V5   V6   V7
#> 1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> 2 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> 3  TRUE FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> 4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> 5  TRUE  TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> 6 FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
...
```

Now assuming I have this right, the solution is a one-liner:

```
result <- apply(Df2, 1, function(i) Df1[i])
```

Now `result` is a list of 128 data frames, one for each of all possible combinations of the columns in `Df1` (including an empty data frame at position 128 for the all-`FALSE` case)

```
head(result)
#> [[1]]
#>           V1         V2       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7
#> 1  0.3735462  3.5117812 3.918977 5.358680 4.835476 6.398106 9.401618
#> 2  1.1836433  2.3898432 3.782136 3.897212 4.746638 5.387974 6.960760
#> 3  0.1643714  1.3787594 3.074565 4.387672 5.696963 6.341120 7.689739
#> 4  2.5952808 -0.2146999 1.010648 3.946195 5.556663 4.870637 7.028002
#> 5  1.3295078  3.1249309 3.619826 2.622940 4.311244 7.433024 6.256727
#> 6  0.1795316  1.9550664 2.943871 3.585005 4.292505 7.980400 7.188792
#> 7  1.4874291  1.9838097 2.844204 3.605710 5.364582 5.632779 5.195041
#> 8  1.7383247  2.9438362 1.529248 3.940687 5.768533 4.955865 8.465555
#> 9  1.5757814  2.8212212 2.521850 5.100025 4.887654 6.569720 7.153253
#> 10 0.6946116  2.5939013 3.417942 4.763176 5.881108 5.864945 9.172612
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>            V2       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7
#> 1   3.5117812 3.918977 5.358680 4.835476 6.398106 9.401618
#> 2   2.3898432 3.782136 3.897212 4.746638 5.387974 6.960760
#> 3   1.3787594 3.074565 4.387672 5.696963 6.341120 7.689739
#> 4  -0.2146999 1.010648 3.946195 5.556663 4.870637 7.028002
#> 5   3.1249309 3.619826 2.622940 4.311244 7.433024 6.256727
#> 6   1.9550664 2.943871 3.585005 4.292505 7.980400 7.188792
#> 7   1.9838097 2.844204 3.605710 5.364582 5.632779 5.195041
#> 8   2.9438362 1.529248 3.940687 5.768533 4.955865 8.465555
#> 9   2.8212212 2.521850 5.100025 4.887654 6.569720 7.153253
#> 10  2.5939013 3.417942 4.763176 5.881108 5.864945 9.172612
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>           V1       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7
#> 1  0.3735462 3.918977 5.358680 4.835476 6.398106 9.401618
#> 2  1.1836433 3.782136 3.897212 4.746638 5.387974 6.960760
#> 3  0.1643714 3.074565 4.387672 5.696963 6.341120 7.689739
#> 4  2.5952808 1.010648 3.946195 5.556663 4.870637 7.028002
#> 5  1.3295078 3.619826 2.622940 4.311244 7.433024 6.256727
#> 6  0.1795316 2.943871 3.585005 4.292505 7.980400 7.188792
#> 7  1.4874291 2.844204 3.605710 5.364582 5.632779 5.195041
#> 8  1.7383247 1.529248 3.940687 5.768533 4.955865 8.465555
#> 9  1.5757814 2.521850 5.100025 4.887654 6.569720 7.153253
#> 10 0.6946116 3.417942 4.763176 5.881108 5.864945 9.172612
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>          V3       V4       V5       V6       V7
#> 1  3.918977 5.358680 4.835476 6.398106 9.401618
#> 2  3.782136 3.897212 4.746638 5.387974 6.960760
#> 3  3.074565 4.387672 5.696963 6.341120 7.689739
#> 4  1.010648 3.946195 5.556663 4.870637 7.028002
#> 5  3.619826 2.622940 4.311244 7.433024 6.256727
#> 6  2.943871 3.585005 4.292505 7.980400 7.188792
#> 7  2.844204 3.605710 5.364582 5.632779 5.195041
#> 8  1.529248 3.940687 5.768533 4.955865 8.465555
#> 9  2.521850 5.100025 4.887654 6.569720 7.153253
#> 10 3.417942 4.763176 5.881108 5.864945 9.172612
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>           V1         V2       V4       V5       V6       V7
#> 1  0.3735462  3.5117812 5.358680 4.835476 6.398106 9.401618
#> 2  1.1836433  2.3898432 3.897212 4.746638 5.387974 6.960760
#> 3  0.1643714  1.3787594 4.387672 5.696963 6.341120 7.689739
#> 4  2.5952808 -0.2146999 3.946195 5.556663 4.870637 7.028002
#> 5  1.3295078  3.1249309 2.622940 4.311244 7.433024 6.256727
#> 6  0.1795316  1.9550664 3.585005 4.292505 7.980400 7.188792
#> 7  1.4874291  1.9838097 3.605710 5.364582 5.632779 5.195041
#> 8  1.7383247  2.9438362 3.940687 5.768533 4.955865 8.465555
#> 9  1.5757814  2.8212212 5.100025 4.887654 6.569720 7.153253
#> 10 0.6946116  2.5939013 4.763176 5.881108 5.864945 9.172612
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>            V2       V4       V5       V6       V7
#> 1   3.5117812 5.358680 4.835476 6.398106 9.401618
#> 2   2.3898432 3.897212 4.746638 5.387974 6.960760
#> 3   1.3787594 4.387672 5.696963 6.341120 7.689739
#> 4  -0.2146999 3.946195 5.556663 4.870637 7.028002
#> 5   3.1249309 2.622940 4.311244 7.433024 6.256727
#> 6   1.9550664 3.585005 4.292505 7.980400 7.188792
#> 7   1.9838097 3.605710 5.364582 5.632779 5.195041
#> 8   2.9438362 3.940687 5.768533 4.955865 8.465555
#> 9   2.8212212 5.100025 4.887654 6.569720 7.153253
#> 10  2.5939013 4.763176 5.881108 5.864945 9.172612

#> (etc)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Allan, that's very clear.